# Couldn't load plugin 'processing' in QGIS 2.18.14

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing

I'm using QGIS 2.18.14 on a windows 10 home, version 1709 and OS build 16299.98. After the recent update I get the following message:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'processing' 

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 308, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 31, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 55, in 
    from processing.algs.qgis.QGISAlgorithmProvider import QGISAlgorithmProvider
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\QGISAlgorithmProvider.py", line 110, in 
    from .RasterLayerStatistics import RasterLayerStatistics
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\RasterLayerStatistics.py", line 36, in 
    from processing.tools import raster
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\raster.py", line 29, in 
    import numpy
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 187, in 
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in 
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in 
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in 
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 6, in 
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.14 Las Palmas, ff83b9a479 

Python Path:
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/quercus/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/quercus/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\python27.zip
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27
c:\osgeo4~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
c:\osgeo4~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
c:\osgeo4~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/quercus/.qgis2//python
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: Most probably the Python 2.7 from ArcGIS kills your QGIS python 2.7. You need to remove it from the path variable.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. After I remove the Arcgis python path problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I removed the ArcGIS python path from environment variables, the problem was solved.